# Username display overidden by customer profile name

Tags: 7, commerce

If a user has a customer profile (i.e. ever filled out a shopping cart) the name in the profile is used everywhere their username is displayed.

This results in a lot of confusion for our moderators/admins.  Because when they go to lookup a user in admin/people they're looking for the username that the user logs in with.  But what's displayed is their "nice" name from their shipping address.  I need to undo this override because it's way too confusing.

It doesn't look like anyone is doing this through theme_username().  Where is this display override happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

`commerce_kickstart_user_username_alter()` is overwriting usernames with the name provided in their addressbook.

I implemented my own `hook_username_alter()` to simply return `$account->name`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Real Name](https://drupal.org/project/realname) module to configure how display names are shown. It's a bit overkill because you just want it to be back to the username.

You could write your own lightweight module to theme the username back to the actual username. via [`theme_username`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_username/7)`

> Returns HTML for a username, potentially linked to the user's page.